# Loop through array in ThymeLeaf

Tags: arrays, loops, thymeleaf, paragraph

I am new to ThymeLeaf and I was wondering if there was a way to loop around a `<p>` html tag as well as iterate through an array within that `<p>` tag. I want the elements within `smokeTest` to end up in different paragraphs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="${smokeTests[0].name}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Did you try the following code? I didn't test it, cause it's often used :

```
<body>
    <p th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}"
       th:text="${smokeTest.name}">A Smoke Test</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

This pretty straight forward. You can do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}" th:text="${smokeTest.name}"><p/>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use some other html tags other than paragraph tag. Like this:

```
<h2 th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}" th:text="${smokeTest.name}"><h2/>
```